# Transfor XML data to fields in a form (different types of nodes)

Tags: php

I have an XML file like this:

```
<Property>
    <id>104</id>
    <value>
        <error-code>
            <ok/>
        </error-code>
    </value>
</Property>
<Property>
    <id>7</id>
    <value>
        <real>1.829490E+02</real>
    </value>
</Property>
<Property>
    <id>8</id>
    <value>
        <real>-4.043700E+01</real>
    </value>
</Property>
<Property>
    <id>104</id>
    <value>
        <error-code>
            <ok/>
        </error-code>
    </value>
</Property>
<Property>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>
        <int>9600</int>
    </value>
</Property>
```

As you can see there are some nodes labelled as `real` and other labelled as `int`. I should create some input fields from those values, so I have created something like this:

```
foreach ($item['properties'][0]['Property'] as $property) {

    if (isset($property['value'][0]['real'])) {
        $html .= "<tr>" .
            "<td>" . $property['name'] . "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $property['id'][0] . "</td>" .
            '<td><input name="property_' .  $property['property_id'] . '" value="' . $property['value'][0]['real'][0] . '"></td>' .
            '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' . $property['property_id'] . '"></td>' .
        '</tr>';
    } else if (isset($property['value'][0]['int'])) {
        $html .= "<tr>" .
            "<td>" . $property['name'] . "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $property['id'][0] . "</td>" .
            '<td><input value="' . $property['value'][0]['int'][0] . '"></td>' .
            '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' . $property['property_id'] . '"></td>' .
         '</tr>';
     }
}
```

As you can see I have created a couple of `if` statement to get the value from `int` or `real`. To be sincere, this doesn't look like very smart way to do it, since maybe in the future there will be more types of data. Any suggestion about how to implemente this in a smarter way?

Comment: Maybe with `switch`?

Comment: If you refactored the common code, it would come down to just the `<input...` that is different (as far as I can tell) which would help.